# Run DynamoDB locally with Java command on Mac

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have been following the steps in the documentation here to set up DynamoDB locally:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html

After downloading the jar file from the link, I ran the following command in the directory where I extracted the jar file: `java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

Then I ran:
`aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

I have already configured my AWS credentials and ensured that I'm using the correct AWS region code but I can't connect to the end point URL. I get the following error:
`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"`

Any ideas? Thanks!

This is from my error log:

```
Jul 13, 2020 3:35:17 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: stopped abnormally, reincarnating in 3000ms
Jul 13, 2020 3:35:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[24]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [./DynamoDBLocal_lib]
Jul 13, 2020 3:35:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: error running job queue
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [./DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [./DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2680)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:807)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1907)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Are you running local ddb inside a vm?

Comment: No, I'm not running it inside vm

Comment: That's weird. Could you try other ports?

Comment: I changed it to port 8001 but that doesn't help. I forgot to add the error log that says something about no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path.